# how to prove $a+b-ab \le 1$ if $a,b \in [0,1]$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Given:

$0 \le a \le 1$

$0 \le b \le 1$

Prove: $a + b - ab \le 1$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: in that interval,
$$(1-a)(1-b) \ge 0$$

Answer (score 1):

$$ab-a-b+1=(a-1)(b-1)\ge 0$$ since $a-1\le0$ and $b-1\le 0$.